# Создает ли SQLite индексы автоматически?

Tags: sqlite

Создает ли SQLite индексы автоматически при объявлении первичного ключа? внешнего ключа? Или создавать их нужно вручную?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite создает индексы автоматически в ряде случаев.

> ... both UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints are implemented by creating an index in the database (in the same way as a "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX" statement would). Such an index is used like any other index in the database to optimize queries ...

[Источник](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).